# WC Vendor - Create Order Programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, wcvendors

I am trying to create a order in WC Vendor using a custom route with rest api, the problem is that the vendors doesn't see their order, although the orders are create in Woocommerce.

Any ideas on how to add the orders to the corresponding vendor?

Also why the orders doesn't show in WC Vendor dashboard?

Below is the code I'm using to create a order.

```
function create_vendors_order(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  $params = $request->get_json_params();
  $vendor_id = $params['vendor_id'];
  $buyer_id = $params['buyer_id'];
  $product_id = $params['product_id'];
  $vendor_commission_rate = get_user_meta($vendor_id, '_wcv_commission', true);

  // Calculate the vendor's commission amount based on the product price and commission rate
  $product_price = get_post_meta($product_id, '_price', true);
  $vendor_commission = $product_price * $vendor_commission_rate / 100;

  // Create a new order
  $order = wc_create_order(array('status' => 'completed'));

  // Add the product to the order
  $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
  $item = new WC_Order_Item_Product();
  $item->set_props(array(
    'product' => $product,
    'quantity' => 1,
    'subtotal' => $product_price,
    'total' => $product_price,
    'tax_class' => $product->get_tax_class(),
    'taxes' => array(),
  ));

  $item->add_meta_data('Sold By', get_userdata($vendor_id)->display_name, true); // Add the vendor display name to the order item metadata
  $item->add_meta_data('_sold_by_id', $vendor_id, true); // Add the vendor ID to the order item metadata
  $order->add_item($item);
  // Set the order status to 'pending'
  $order->update_status('pending', __('Order created programmatically', 'your-text-domain'));

  // Set the buyer and vendor IDs on the order
  $order->set_customer_id($buyer_id);
  $order->set_customer_note('This order was created programmatically.');
  $order->add_meta_data('_vendor_id', $vendor_id, true);
  $vendor_id = $order->get_meta('_vendor_id');

  // Set the vendor commission amount and mark it as paid
  $order->add_meta_data('_vendor_total', $vendor_commission, true);
  $order->add_meta_data('_vendor_paid', 'yes', true);

  // Calculate and set the order totals
  $order->calculate_totals();

  $order->save();
  $commission_data = array(
    'post_title'    => sprintf(__('Commission - %s', 'your-text-domain'), $order->get_order_number()),
    'post_content'  => '',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'shop_commission',
  );

  // Insert the commission post into the database
  $commission_id = wp_insert_post($commission_data);

  // Add commission post meta
  update_post_meta($commission_id, '_commission_order_id', $order->get_id());
  update_post_meta($commission_id, '_vendor_id', $vendor_id);
  update_post_meta($commission_id, '_commission_product', $product_id);
  update_post_meta($commission_id, '_commission_amount', $vendor_commission);
  update_post_meta($commission_id, '_order_total', $product_price);
  update_post_meta($commission_id, '_product_quantity', 1);

  return array(
    'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
    'vendor_id' => $order->get_meta('_vendor_id'),
  );
}
```